# how to create an object with user input javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object

```js
window.onload = Soldier;

function Soldier(allegiance,armor,weapon){
    this.allegiance = allegiance;
    this.armor = armor;
    this.weapon = weapon;
}
document.getElementById("soldier").innerHTML = 

var soldier1 =  new Soldier("Theosis", true, "Sword");
alert(soldier1.allegiance);
```

```html
<DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
    <script src = "objscript.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
  Allegiance: <input type ="text" id = "allegiance"><br/><br/>
  Armor:  <input type ="text" id = "armor"><br/><br/>
  Weapon(s): <input type ="text" id = "weapon"><br/><br/>
  <input type = "button" id="button" value = "Submit"><br/>
  <p id = "soldier"> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

i know how to make objects but i dont know how to make the user input the data of the object and print onto the screen.

Comment: When are you prompting the user to enter their input? You appear to be using standard `<input>` boxes, but are attempting to set the `Soldier` on page load (before the user could have entered any values). Would it be suitable to assign to the object on clicking a button? Or are you looking to store this info in a `COOKIE` or similar?

Answer (score -1):

The solution:

**HTML**

```
Allegiance: <input type ="text" id = "allegiance"><br/><br/>
Armor:  <input type ="text" id = "armor"><br/><br/>
Weapon(s): <input type ="text" id = "weapon"><br/><br/>
<input type = "button" id="button" onclick="hire()" value = "Submit"><br/>
<p id="output"></p>
```

**JS**

```
var soldiers = [];

function Soldier(allegiance, armor, weapon){
  this.allegiance = allegiance;
  this.armor = armor;
  this.weapon = weapon;
  this.doReport = function () {
    return this.armor + ' and ' + this.weapon;
  }
}

function doReport() {
   output = "";
   for(var i = 0; i < soldiers.length; i++) {
      output += (i + 1) + ") " + soldiers[i].doReport() + "; ";
   }
   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}

function hire() {
  var soldier =  new Soldier(
    document.getElementById("allegiance").value, 
    document.getElementById("armor").value, 
    document.getElementById("weapon").value
  );
  soldiers.push(soldier);
  doReport();
}
```

I added function `hire()` and bound it with submit button. A new `soldier` object is being pushed into the list of `soldiers`. Also I added `doReport()` method to `Soldier` and common `doReport()` function which makes a general report of all soldiers in the list. Right now, I call `doReport()` in the end of each `hire()`, but you can do it by clicking on some another button for example.

Comment: @BrandonBell Open a brower console, I output it out via ` console.log`. There is no code for output in in html. BTW, I can add it...

Comment: o ok. ya thats exactly what i need. and then i need another button to actually print the soldiers all at once on the page. how would i do that?

Comment: @BrandonBell Considering you asked a [**second question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46801380) for the table, utilising this very code, I would recommend marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I'm afraid, he may not understand the workflow :-/

Answer (score -1):

```js
window.onload = submit;
function Soldier(allegiance,armor,weapon){
this.allegiance = "allegiance";
this.armor = armor;
this.weapon = weapon;


var soldier1 =  document.getElementById("atext").value;

document.getElementById("soldier").innerHTML = " allegiance: " + soldier.allegiance + " <br/> " + " armor: " + soldier.armor + "</br>" + "Weapon(s): "+ soldier.weapon;
}

function submit(){
 var submitButton = document.getElementById("button");
 submitButton.onclick = Soldier;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<script src = "objscript.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
Allegiance: <input type ="text" id = "atext"><br/><br/>
Armor:  <input type ="text" id = "armor"><br/><br/>
Weapon(s): <input type ="text" id = "weapon"><br/><br/>
<input type = "button" id="button" value = "Submit"><br/>
<p id = "soldier"> </p>

</body>
</html>
```

I dont think im allowed to use push. im just suppose to make new soldiers by the user typing it in. i made the code a little better. now just need it to actually print